# Choosing proper CCS current for discrete transistor amplifier's differential and VAS stages

Tags: transistors, amplifier, differential, constant-current, bias

Here is a figure from "Audio Power Amplifier Design" by Douglas Self. Self using almost same current values (4mA and 6-8mA) in many examples without explanation. How to choose these values properly for my own design?

[image]

Comment: It's hard to go argue with a "model" design (which isn't realy a design) or a book someone else wrote (which can't debate you.) First, what is the book edition, specifically, from which this picture is taken? Second, have you READ IT? He does talk about the subject at some length in his 5th edition here. Also, the need for R7's current is different than the need for R11's (which is less important to pin down.) Perhaps you can narrow your question? It's way too broad as it is, since any answer would involve a complete design process.

Comment: Oh, and what exactly IS your design to achieve? Forgot to ask that.